# Evento onClick não está funcionando!

Tags: jquery

Evento `$('.target').on('click', function(){})` em um botão que estou carregando via `ajax`, mas não funciona, acredito que seja por causa do conteúdo ainda não estar carregado na página, então o '.target' não existe quando a página é carregada.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
$(".bseguir").on('click',function(){
    alert('oi');
});


$.getJSON('pagina.php',function(data){
      $.each(data,function(){
          html = '<li class="qf b aml">\
                  <button class="bseguir" id="">Seguir</button>\
                  </li>';

          $('#lista').append(html);
      })
  });
```

Comment: Poderia colocar a parte do `html` que contém o elemento? Creio que facilitaria o entendimento da sua questão...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resposta rápida

Você pode anexar o evento à um elemento pai que esteja fixo no HTML. Dessa forma, você não precisará dar o bind para os elementos criados dinamicamente.

No exemplo abaixo, estou criando botões dinamicamente que já possuem o `onclick`, pois o mesmo está configurado para todos os filhos de `#lista` com a classe `.bsseguir`,

```js
$("#lista").on("click", ".bsseguir", function() {
  $("#lista")
    .append($("<li>")
      .append($('<button>')
        .attr('class', 'bsseguir')
        .append("Seguir")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="lista">
  <li>
    <button class="bsseguir">Seguir</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Mas... por que isso acontece?

Segundo a documentação do próprio jQuery,

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure
>   the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the
>   elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document
>   ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event
>   handlers.

Os eventos são *anexados* apenas para os elementos selecionados que existirem no `DOM` no momento em que você realizar a chamada ao método `.on()`. Para garantir que estes elementos estejam presentes no momento da chamada, você pode colocar o script depois das marcações *HTML* ou utilizar o `document.ready` para aguardar todo o carregamento do `DOM`. Contudo, esta não é a realidade de elementos criados dinamicamente, onde você pode utilizar *delegated events* como alternativa.

E o *Delegated Event* é o que construímos no exemplo anterior, onde um evento é anexado à um elemento pai existente na execução do `.on()`, informando também um seletor responsável pelo gatilho que irá disparar este evento. Além da facilidade com os elementos dinâmicos, você estará criando apenas um evento que pode ser disparado por diversos elementos, causando menos overhead do que criar um evento para cada elemento que possa dispara-lo.

Comment: Acho que a resposta ótima, só corrige que não é `$("#menu")` e sim `$("#lista")`, mas ainda sim está ok a explicação.

Comment: Não tinha visto o #lista, atualizando a resposta...

Comment: Matou a pau Vinícius... Muito obrigado pela reposta. Já está resolvido!

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues que bom! Se resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como correta clicando no V abaixo dos pontos dela (:

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, basta inserir o `bind` na sequencia:

```
$.getJSON('pagina.php',function(data){
  $.each(data,function(){
      html = '<li class="qf b aml">\
              <button class="bseguir" id="">Seguir</button>\
              </li>';

      $('#lista').append(html);
      $(".bseguir").on('click',function(){
        alert('oi');
      });
  })
});
```

Um recurso técnico não catalogado (vulgo gambiarra) que você pode utilizar é:

```
$(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.target').on('click', function(){});
    }, 2000); //Aqui você regula um tempo seguro em que o botão já estará carregado
});
```

Considerando que o `ajax` não seja executado automaticamente, dependendo de alguma ação, aconselho a colocar o código no `success` do `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    success: function(data){
        //...
        //após inserir seu código, você atrela o evento
        $('.target').on('click', function(){});
    }
});
```

Comment: Não seria melhor ensina a usar `promises` em vez de gambiarras?